# fail2ban to block 403 errors apache

Tags: apache, joomla

I'm fighting with fail2ban to block brute force attacks on Joomla admin pages.

With an extension in Joomla I can block a IP so an error message will appear.

In apache log this gives the following logline;

```
domain.com:80 146.185.150.198 - - [16/Jun/2014:21:29:09 +0200] "GET /administrator/index.php HTTP/1.0" 403 358 "-" "-"
```

domain.com can be different since there are many domains on the servers.

I do have the following config in fail2ban

jail.local

```
[administrator]
enabled = true
port    = http,https
filter  = administrator
action   = iptables-multiport[name=ALL, port="http,https"]
logpath = /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log
maxretry = 3
```

filter.d/administrator.conf

```
[Definition]
failregex = [].<HOST> .*HTTP/[0-9.]+" 403
ignoreregex =
```

I also tried as failregex: `^<HOST> -.GET.*administrator.*.HTTP\/1.0".* 403 .*$`

Neither are working.

Who has the right config to get this working?

Comment: Looks great. I will test it the coming days

Answer (score 2):

Finaly got it working, bit different then expected;

My filter:

```
 failregex = .* <HOST> - - .*(POST|GET) .*administrator/index.php HTTP.* 403 .*$
```

This is working great now, catching even more login attempts as excepted

Comment: Why don't you accept your own answer if it solved the original issue?

Answer (score 2):

i wrote this plugin

http://www.rupostel.com/joomla/hacks/blocking-joomla-brute-force-login-attacks-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-server
(requires php5.4+)

based on
http://baxeico.wordpress.com/2014/03/31/joomla-brute-force-attacks-file2ban/

and added this to fail2ban config:

\etc\fail2ban\jail.local

```
[joomla-error]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = joomla-error
logpath = /var/log/joomla.log
maxretry = 7
findtime = 6000
bantime  = 17200
```

\etc\fail2ban\filter.d\joomla-error.conf

```
[Definition]

# Option: failregex
# Notes.: matches something like:
# [Mon Mar 31 10:15:00 2014] [error] [client 212.109.14.203] user mywebsite authentication failure
# Values: TEXT
failregex = [[]client <HOST>[]] user .* authentication failure.*

# Option: ignoreregex
# Notes.: regex to ignore. If this regex matches, the line is ignored.
# Values: TEXT
#
ignoreregex =
```

\etc\rsyslog.d\10-joomla.conf

```
if $programname == 'joomla' then /var/log/joomla.log
```

The plugin sends the authentication error into syslog which even when the pool is inside a chroot makes it possible to use system wide fail2ban with the iptables.

Comment: Tried to install the plugin. Result was a none working Joomla site. So I will do some more tests to find the problem.

Comment: - hello, until 2nd dec 2014, it supported only php5.4+ Now i updated the code to run on php5.3. I am using this on 100 joomla sites, all of them are inside a chroot ranging from joomla 1.5, 2.5 to 3.x

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
failregex = ^.* <HOST> .*"(:?GET|POST|HEAD) .* 403 [0-9]{3}.*
```

Or you can play with it in the online regexp tester: http://regex101.com/r/jQ7wQ9/2